# move all the folders and files to the folder with the same subject name in the directory Linux

Tags: linux

I have for example 001, 001_ses-1, 001_ses-2 folders and files 001_lg1.lsf, 001_recon1.lsf, 001_trac1.lsf in the same directory. I have hundreds of subjects.
I want to move folders: 001_ses-1, 001_ses-2, and files: 001_lg1.lsf , recon1_001.lsf and trac1_001.lsf to 001 main folder. How do I do this?

```
list={001, 011, 023, 059, ..... 102}
for i in list; do rm i* i; done
```

so far, I have no clues. Need some help figuring it out!

Comment: You need to clarify some things: Do the folders already exist, or do you need to create them? Are the folder names always a 3 digit number? What files do you want to move to a folder - all files that start with the name of the folder?

Comment: 1) folders already exist. 2) 3 digit number for ID is an example. Real Id is much complicated: XXX_S_XXX. X are digits.  3) move ID_suffix folders and ID_suffix files to the ID folder. thank you !

Comment: Are the destination folders in a separate location then the files and folders you want to move, or are they all mixed together in the same folder? I am asking because there may be a solution to iterate over the IDs automatically instead of writing a manual list.

Comment: they mixed together in the same folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the information provided in the comments, there are two possibilities for identifying the destination folders:

A) Create a manual list. This is how it is done in Bash and compatible Linux shells:

```
DEST_LIST=( "001" "002" "003" "004" ) 

for DEST in ${DEST_LIST[@]}; do
    mv "${DEST}_"* "${DEST}"
```

B) Create a regular expression of the pattern and use `find`.
I will use the pattern from your comment as an example:

```
PREFIX_PATTERN="[0-9]\{3\}_S_[0-9]\{3\}\.[0-9]"

for DEST in $(find . -type d -regex ".*/${PREFIX_PATTERN}"); do
    PREFIX=`expr "${DEST}" : ".*\(${PREFIX_PATTERN}\)"`
    mv "${PREFIX}_"* "${DEST}"
```

The extra line containing the `expr` command extracts the clean folder name from the full folder path returned by `find` command.

Comment: thanks! the first one worked. one thing: 'mv' don't have a '-r' option as 'cp'. for DEST in ${DEST_LIST[@]}; do
    mv "${DEST}_"* "${DEST}"; done

Comment: @zenoZeng you are absolutely right about `-r`, I fixed the answer in case someone else finds it useful.